# CASE syntax inside a WHERE clause with IN on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

How can I make following query work? This is inside stored procedure `@GetClosedMeetings` `bit` parameter passed true to get the meetings which are finished, otherwise get planned and current meetings. (Status: 0 - Planned, 1 - Current, 2 - closed)

```
SELECT 
    MeetingId, Status
FROM 
    dbo.Meeting
WHERE 
    Status IN  (CASE 
                   WHEN @GetClosedMeetings = 1 THEN 1 
                   ELSE @OtherStatuses)
```

Comment: I think you wanted  `WHEN @GetClosedMeetings = 1 THEN 2`. And do not forget the `END`

Comment: What is in @OtherStatuses and @GetClosedMeetings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed end in case

```
SELECT MeetingId, Status
FROM dbo.Meeting
WHERE Status IN 
(CASE 
 WHEN @GetClosedMeetings = 1 THEN 1 
 ELSE @OtherStatuses end)
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your requirement correctly, if `@GetClosedMeetings` is `TRUE`, you want to return `Meetings` that are finished, which from your question seems to have a `STATUS` of 2. On the other hand, if `@GetClosedMeetings` is `FALSE`, then you want to get planned and current meetings. Here is one way to achieve this:

```
SELECT MeetingId, Status
FROM dbo.Meeting
WHERE
    (@GetClosedMeetings = 1 AND Status = 2)
    OR (@GetClosedMeetings = 0 AND Status IN(0, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
SELECT MeetingId, Status
FROM dbo.Meeting
WHERE (Status = 1 And @GetClosedMeetings = 1)
Or (Status <> 1 And @GetClosedMeetings <> 1 )
```

Comment: works in this case, but if Closed meetings relates to more than one status, it wont I guess. Anyway Thanks.